# Calculating resistance of an electric brush

Tags: current, resistance, materials

For a certain application, I'm using carbon based brushes to transmit power from a stationary component to a moving component. I'd like to calculate the resistance of the carbon based brushes to know the maximum current it can carry without problems. I did the same with the copper using the following formula:

$$R = \frac{\rho L}{A}$$

Is it valid to use the same formula with the brushes?

Where the resistivity of carbon is: 2.50E−6 to 5.00E−6

Also, if low voltage and high current is applied between the surfaces of each component is an arc possible? There should be no gaps at all, all surfaces are in direct contact.

Comment: Arcing is only going to occur if there's lots of power and a gap develops (think arc welding...), but unless you're moving several tens of amps or a hundred volts or so, any arcs that develop probably won't last long - they just won't have the power to keep going.

Comment: Does say (without specifying) "high" current.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0wXJ2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think you'll find the resistance dominated by the rotating interface between the carbon and the copper, not by the carbon.

My general experience suggests that arcs a quite possible, but I guess that is mostly with slotted motor armatures rather than dead-smooth slip rings. But I'd hesitate to assume otherwise without testing.